# Detect Outgoing Calls Reject Reason in Android

Tags: android

Is is possible to detect network reject reason for outgoing calls in Android?

For example, let's assume a person is out of credit and is attempting a phone call. In this case, the Network will reject the call (since the person is out of credit). How can an App detect this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not possible mate!
The call reject on out of credit is managed by the service provider, which has no API that can be used in apps.

Comment: My line of thinking is that the phone must receive a reject reason from the network (i.e. that's how I see messages like "Network is busy" or "Called party is not available"). I'm just trying to filter and pick up the reject message/code.

Comment: Well, these APIs are not accessible to you as long as you think you are a programmer. If you think you are a hacker, then good luck. Having a rooted device may help as well.

Answer (score 0):

A "bit" late xD, but I believe you're looking for this: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/DisconnectCause.java. I just found it with help of what you said on one of the error codes: "Network is busy" --> searched "network is busy site:android.googlesource.com" on Google, without the quotes (saying this because they matter on Google searches, in case anyone didn't know).

That's DisconnectCause class and there's also PreciseDisconnectCause: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/PreciseDisconnectCause.java. You can know this last one because on the first one, it's said that class is used on PhoneStateListener on `onCallDisconnectCauseChanged()` (which may be what you want), and on Android Developers, we can see that method has 2 parameters, which give 404 error on Android Developers. So I seached the .java class file on Google for Android Source links and there they are.

Notes on using this method:

- it requires API 30 at minimum (pity...);
- but more important, it requires `READ_PRECISE_PHONE_STATE` (the app must be installed as system app) - or some other trick with root commands.